# UITabbarController layout issues in iOS 7 - view going behind the navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm working on mobile solution which needs to be upgraded to iOS 7. I've a tabbar controller with 4 tabs which is embedded in a Navigation Controller. All 4 view controllers of tab bar  are having a tableview laid at (0,0) origin and set to size of view with resizing handles set properly.
When I launch the application, the table view in the first tab bar item is displaying properly below the navigation item where as the table views in the remaining 3 tabbar items are going below the navigation item. The base controller is same for all view controllers in which I've set the following code.

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:)]) {
    [self performSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:UIRectEdgeNone]];
}
```

I've also deselected "Under Top Bars" & "Under Bottom Bars" under "Extend Edges" section in storyboard for the concerned view controllers. But still the issue remains same.

Any inputs on this would help me a lot.

Thanks

Sudheer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The issue has been fixed by setting setEdgesForExtentedLayout to UIRectEdgeNone to UITabbarController rather than setting it to each and individual view controllers in the tab bar.

Comment: This answer SAVED MY ENTIRE LIFE. Thank you! I've been struggling with a view controller that kept sliding under the toolbar. Setting the edgesForExtendedLayout in the tab bar controller instead of in the content view fixed it for me.

Comment: Worked perfectly. I never would have guessed this. Thanks!

Comment: In the storyboard, it's Tab Bar Controller / uncheck Extend Edges: Under Top Bar.  This answer got me there.  Thank you!

Comment: @Burke Holland I have unchecked the Extend Edges, but there's a strange problem; a black shadow appears in the navigation bar on right side. I have the default tint & background colors. [Please see  the video here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ao97l5gq043lm2a/TabBar_Extend_Edges_Issue.gif?dl=0)

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.translucent = NO;
```

Comment: Identified that the issue is because of using the main navigation controller to the tabbar items as well. Hopefully each tabbar item should have a separate navigation controller but the current project is not designed as such. Tried adding a navigation controller to one tabbar item and it's working as expected, but now changing for the entire project takes more code changes. Any alternate solution without adding new navigation controllers to each tabbar item?

Comment: Mutawe, your solution didn't help me out. Still resulting in the same issue.